# Spring Data check if property not null in Query

Tags: spring, spring-data

I used query annotation to find by embedded object property, but the version property Can be null, how can i check in the query if the version is not null

```
@Query("{ 'settingVersion.version' : ?2 }")
Setting findByLevelAndClientId(SettingsLevel level, String clientId, String version);
```

Comment: Why don't you check for nullity before invoking this?

Comment: @EmanuelRamirez because i want if version is null i find by level and client and if not i find by level and client and version

Comment: Then i think what you need is the Criteria API, i think this needs to be handled programatically. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications

Answer (score 0):

You could write the hql query on @Query annnotation like this:

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Setting s WHERE (s.version is null and s.level = :level and s.clientId = clientId) or (s.version is not null and s.version = :version)")
Setting findByLevelAndClientId(@Param("level") SettingsLevel level, String @Param("clientId") clientId, @Param("version") String version);
```